# ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: cannot import name '_ADDITIONAL_CHECKS' from 'ansible.module_utils.common.parameters'

Tags: ansible

I have the following setup script that always fails

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
pipx install virtualenv
pipx install awscli
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
ansible-galaxy install -r ansible/ansible_requirements.yml

if [ ! -d "${HOME}/.aws" ]
then
    echo "${HOME}/.aws does not exist"
    echo "you need to make sure you awscli is correctly configured... invoking configure"
    aws configure
fi
```

Here is the following error

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: cannot import name '_ADDITIONAL_CHECKS' from 'ansible.module_utils.common.parameters' (/home/user100/sagainfra/infrastructure/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/module_utils/common/parameters.py)
```

my `ansible_requirements.yml`

```
collections:
  - name: amazon.aws
  - name: community.general
  - name: kubernetes.core
```

Here is the `requirements.txt`. I already tried minimizing this list and I still face the same issue

```
ansible
ansible-base
ansible-lint
awscli
boto3
botocore
bracex
cffi
click
colorama
commonmark
cryptography
enrich
Jinja2
jmespath
loguru
MarkupSafe
netaddr
packaging
paramiko
prettytable
pyasn1
pycparser
Pygments
pyparsing
python-dateutil
PyYAML
rich
ruamel.yaml
ruamel.yaml.clib
s3transfer
six
tenacity
urllib3
wcmatch
yaspin
pre-commit
```

How to fix?

Comment: what libraries are installed in `requirements.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

with same error, I get it work with:

**Disclaimer:**
Do it only if you know what you're doing and if you're sure to have no software that requires python2.x.

To use python2.x softwares without have dependencies conflicts, use **Python Virtual Environments**.

1. Uninstall Python 2.x:
   do it for all versions 2, 2.7, 2.8, etc...)

   ```
   sudo apt remove python2
   ```
2. Cleanup your system for python2.x dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt -y autoremove
   ```
3. Upgrade your ansible version using pip3:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install ansible --upgrade
   ```

Comment: I just had to remove `ansible-base` and remove venv and reinstall

Comment: Does this not work with ansible-base?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles over this, what reproducibly fixed it for me was reinstalling Ansible with the same version already installed.

```
pip3 install --force 'ansible==5.2.0'
```